# Function Name Conventions(Any Kind of PL)

Tags: java, php, .net, c++, vb.net

Is it bad to use Underscores in Function Names? Can I know the reason why?
ie:
Function GET_NAME(byval sword as string) as string

Comment: Not an answer, but the underscore is most widely used in languages like SQL where case-sensitivity is absent. It makes sense to name a table as CUSTOMER_DETAILS rather than CustomerDetails, for the database would treat customerdetails the same as Customerdetails or the original CustomerDetails.

Answer (score 2):

**Not at all**. The coding convention is a very **subjective** term. One might feel one coding style great and another find it worse. The key point is **maintain one coding style** only throughout your code for ease of upcoming developers and maintainers.

However, avoid all caps for function names (as shown in your example). It's generally reserved for  *macros (C/C++) / constants*.

Answer (score 0):

I would use them sparingly in my own API, but to say that they are *bad* is simply untrue. If so, .NET specifically would have problems with default naming for event handlers!

```
void Form_Load( //...
void Page_Load( //...
void btn_Click( //...
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, all caps with underscore separators are generally understood to be constant values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, its very ***subjective matter*** and depends from Person to Person. One may feel like using _ in function, others may not. There's no harm if you use it.

Frankly speaking, you don't usually use `_` sign. But, you can to use this '`_`' in the variable declaration.

---

> **Note :** You can check out the [`msdn link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) ( atleast for  C#,
>   Visual Basic, C++ )

Comment: Uh, you've never seen `std::for_each`?

Comment: @ildjarn : Ahh ! yes .. I have seen it.